# XML deserializer when the target class does not deserialize properly

Tags: c#, json, xml, deserialization

I have a class `Point` that I created that uses `Length` types from UnitsNet nuget package that does unit conversions:

```
public class Point
{
    public Point() { }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Point(Length x, Length y, Length z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public Length X { get; set; }
    public Length Y { get; set; }
    public Length Z { get; set; }
}
```

This class is then used by other classes that I created (like `Line`) as a public property:

```
public class Line
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Point StartPoint { get; set; } = new(new Length(), new Length(), new Length());
    public Point EndPoint { get; set; } = new(new Length(), new Length(), new Length());
}
```

When I deserialize the `Line` object using XML that looks like this I get zeros for the values of length:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<File>
    <Name>Sketch2</Name>
    <Line>
      <Name>Line4</Name>
      <Volume>28.30188679245283</Volume>
      <StartPoint>
        <X>0.71161836352506369</X>
        <Y>0.44158426707323123</Y>
        <Z>0</Z>
      </StartPoint>
      <EndPoint>
        <X>0.79110301979189424</X>
        <Y>0.596011599248788</Y>
        <Z>0</Z>
      </EndPoint>
    </Line>
</File>
```

Now I think I will have an issue with this XML because it does not specify what units(Meter, mm, cm, etc.) the double value should be.

It feels like I need to manually create a deserializer for the `Point` or for `Length`. This may not be the right path at all though.

I have tried converting the XML to JSON as it seems that JSON deserialization has better control. The JSON deserializes but I still don't get values for the X, Y and Z in Point. I have burned about a day on this and I think I need some direction as to the right way to do this.

Comment: What XML serializer are you using?  Can you share a [mcve] showing your deserialization code?  According to its [docs](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet/wiki/Serializing-to-JSON,-XML-and-more#datacontractserializer-for-xml) UnitsNet supports `DataContractSerializer` but makes no mention of `XmlSerializer`.  Also, is your XML file format fixed, or can you modify it as required?

Comment: Here's an example of the XML generated for your `Point` class: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UgzVzv.  As you can see the XML for `Length` isn't just a number, it contains the units as well as the value.  On the other hand `XmlSerializer` doesn't seem to work at all, the XML it generates for `Length` is empty, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/LhSGdT.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a **SUPER HACKY**, inelegant solution. I came up with this through (*cough*, *cough*) various methods available on the internet.

```
[DataContract]
public class Point
{
    private double _x;
    public Point() { }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "X")]
    public double InitializerX
    {
        get => _x;
        set
        {
            _x = value;
            X = new Length(_x, LengthUnit.Meter);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Length X { get; set; }
    public Length Y { get; set; }
    public Length Z { get; set; }

}
```

So many reasons to hate this. First and foremost that it creates this `InitializerX` property is a somewhat confusing version of `public Length X`. Because XML can't deal with private fields, properties, etc. I have to make it public.

Hopefully someone has a better solution then this???

Comment: Is your XML format flexible?  With this solution, the units are not serialized at all, isn't that a problem?  What is the point of using `UnitsNet.Length` if you discard the units?

Comment: That is exactly the problem. The point of the UnitsNet.Length is there are a whole bunch of conversions that need to be done in the codebase. Different machines using different measurement systems that talk to each other through the codebase. Think of the codebase as an intermediary. I am great with initializing the point values as Meters. I am considering searching the XML, taking the X, Y and Z values out and replacing them with the XML needed to deserialize to Length. Just seems like another crappy hack.

Comment: Oh, the XML is already defined and code is built the way it is. I'd hate to change that standard at this point.